# Bash script that counts and prints out the files that start with a specific letter

Tags: linux, bash

**How do i print out all the files of the current directory that start with the letter "k" ?Also needs to count this files.**

I tried some methods but i only got errors or wrong outputs. Really stuck on this as a newbie in bash.

Comment: Thats not bash @9769953

Comment: @0stone0 Whoops; done too many Python questions. OP, apologies!

Comment: Would `find . -depth 1 -type f -name k\*` be okay, or do you want pure bash?

Comment: @0stone0 Your solutions recurses into subdirectories (otherwise, we obviously offer the same solution). The OP specifies "the current directory".

Comment: Damn that was so close I dndn;t even noticed. Forgot -maxdepth 1`, depth should be fine ;)

Comment: @9769953 need it in pure bash.

Comment: Note that it is very rare for a Linux variant to not have `find` installed.

Comment: I'd consider an installation without findutils (`find`, `xargs`) to be broken unless someone gave me a very good reason for their inavailability. Basically, the *purpose* of `bash` scripts is to facilitate the use of the various command line tools. "Pure bash" isn't a thing IMHO.

Comment: @DevSolar The problem then is which versions of these utilities you have at your disposal. POSIX `xargs` has flaws around null bytes and other kinks just like other userland utilities, though `find` should be usable for a robust portable solution (just not with the commonly assumed GNU frills).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure POSIX shell code:

```
count=0
for file in k*; do
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$file"
        count=$((count+1))
    fi
done
printf 'count=%d\n' "$count"
```

- It works correctly (just prints `count=0`) when run in a directory that contains nothing starting with 'k'.
- It doesn't count directories or other non-files (e.g. fifos).
- It counts symlinks to files, but not broken symlinks or symlinks to non-files.
- It works with 'bash' and 'dash', and should work with any POSIX-compliant shell.

Answer (score 1):

To start with: never parse the output of the `ls` command, but use `find` instead.
As `find` basically goes through all subdirectories, you might need to limit that, using the `-maxdepth` switch, use value 1.
In order to count a number of results, you just count the number of lines in your output (in case your output is shown as one piece of output per line, which is the case of the `find` command). Counting a number of lines is done using the `wc -l` command.

So, this comes down to the following command:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "k*" | wc -l
```

Have fun!

Comment: This is helpful advice but it doesn't work in my bash file. Works on terminal but not in pure bash.

Comment: If it works in the terminal then it works in "pure Bash". Or do you mean we cannot use external commands like `find` and `wc`?

Comment: Note that your find command will also find subdirectories starting with a "k".

Comment: As OP wants only **files** (not subdirectories), you'd want `-type f` in there.

Comment: If you are piping lines to `wc`, you are exposing yourself needlessly to some of the problems with parsing `ls` output. A simple workaround is to have `find` print something else than the actual filename, if you have a `find` which supports this; unfortunately, the `-printf` predicate is not fully portable.

Comment: @tripleee is `print0` portable?

Comment: @Green绿色 Nope, even less so. The null byte options are generally GNU only.

Comment: @ΠαναγιωτηςΧριστοπουλος: and why doesn't it work in your bashfile? I'm working in a bash shell here, and the following command is working fine: `echo $(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "k*" | wc -l)`.

Comment: (That's a handsome [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) though.)

Comment: @tripleee: just my way of saying that I don't understand what the author means by "*not working in pure bash*" :-)

Comment: @DevSolar: I followed your advise and edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure Bash solution.

```
files=(k*)
printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"
echo "${#files[@]} files total"
```

The shell expands the wildcard `k*` into the array, thus populating it with a list of matching files. We then print out the array's elements, and their count.

The use of an array avoids the various problems with metacharacters in file names (see e.g. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020), though the syntax is slightly hard on the eyes.

As remarked by pjh, this will include any matching directories in the count, and fail in odd ways if there are no matches (unless you set `nullglob` to true). If avoiding directories is important, you basically have to get the directories into a separate array and exclude those.

To repeat what Dominique also said, [avoid parsing `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Demo of this and various other candidate solutions:
https://ideone.com/XxwTxB

Comment: This may include subdirectories (and other non-files like symlinks and fifos) in the output list and count.  It also has problems if the directory contains nothing starting with 'k'.

Comment: @pjh Thanks; updated slightly to cover these bases.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
VAR="k"
COUNT=$(ls -p ${VAR}* | grep -v ":" | wc -w)
echo -e "Total number of files: ${COUNT}\n" 1>&2
echo -e "Files,that begin with ${VAR} are:\n$(ls -p ${VAR}* | grep -v ":" )" 1>&2
```